# r string match exact words

Tags: r, string

I have a column in a dataframe where each row contains bunch of names and these names are seperated by a comma `,` as shown below

```
Col1
----------------------------------------------------
Missy Monroe, Andy Dalton P, Deny Grove, Easton West
Susan Schmidt, Bella Blu, Dennis Lee H, Georges Madison
Maya Unger, Kal Rapinsky, Richard Izzo, Rob Kolfax
Bismark Bison, Twyla Yellow Bird  Bell, Yost Jefferson
```

I am searching for three names in this column, `Missy Monroe`, or `Dennis Lee`, or `Bismark Bison`  if any one of these names are found then a value `Yes` should be imputed in the second column, if neither of these names are found then value should be No in the second column. The final output should be as follows.

```
Col1                                                           Results
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Missy Monroe, Andy Dalton P, Deny Grove, Easton West           Yes
Susan Schmidt, Bella Blu, Dennis Lee H, Georges Madison        Yes
Maya Unger, Kal Rapinsky, Richard Izzo, Rob Kolfax             No
Bismark Bison, Twyla Yellow Bird  Bell, Yost Jefferson         Yes
```

Any help on accomplishing this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for a data frame df:

```
df$Results <- ifelse(grepl("(Missy Monroe|Dennis Lee|Bismark Bison)",
                           df$Col1), "Yes", "No")
```

The `grepl` function returns TRUE or FALSE, which is a perfect input for `ifelse`.

As @david-arenburg notes, if you are planning on using this column for additional data analysis, it is probably a better idea to construct it as a logical vector rather than a string vector. In this case,

```
df$Results <- grepl("(Missy Monroe|Dennis Lee|Bismark Bison)", df$Col1)
```

will suffice.

Comment: wow i am shaking my head at my stupidity thanks lmo

Comment: Probably just `grepl("(Missy Monroe|Dennis Lee|Bismark Bison)", df$Col1)` would be enough in order to get a logical vector back which is much easier to work with later.

Comment: I take your point, but it is unclear what the OP wants to do with the data later. Perhaps the result will be written to a csv, formatted a bit in a spreadsheet, and then printed for posting on a wall.